# C Runtime-Agnostic, Standalone Library

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

Specifically in MSVC, is it possible to build a library that doesn't require the project that consumes it to use a specific version of the C++ runtime? If so, how would such a feat be accomplished?

I would like to build a library containing, for example, a simple function `F` that in turn calls functions from some version of the MSVC CRT, as well as calling functions from other 3rd-party libraries. The end product should be a library that I can link to any project I like, without causing conflicts in CRT versions, or complaining about redefined CRT symbols, or complaining about missing symbols from 3rd party dependencies that the library consumes.

In other words, I would like to complete encapsulate the details of the implementation of function `F`, exporting only `F` itself.

If such a thing is not at all possible, please provide an explanation as to why it is not feasible. I am open to additional restrictions such as `extern "C"` or requiring that the library be a dll rather than a static library.

Comment: Sure, COM and the winapi would be good examples.  You have to design the api so this is possible.  No exceptions, no std template objects, no objects created on one side that need to be destroyed in the other, no dependency on CRT state (errno, etc).  You can spin something yourself, but fairly doomed to re-invent COM.  Along with the complaints from your library users that your api is unfriendly.

Comment: @HansPassant I do not understand why the internal implemention of my lib should forbid me from using template objects, so long as that doesn't leak into the interface. Dependency on CRT state too should be fine should it not, so long as it is understood that the state is not shared between the code of the lib and other linked modules.

Comment: Hans did say "You have to design **the api** so this is possible" (emphasis mine). Not your internal implementation details, but the API, the application programming interface.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Ah, good point.